# Reason for MPI 'rc' variable and MPI_Get_Count()

Tags: c, mpi, message-passing

In the *ping-pong* program below, what use is the `rc` variable? It is constantly updated but never used.
Plus what does `MPI_Get_Count()` do?

---

```
#include "mpi.h" 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv []) 

int numtasks, rank, dest, source, rc, count, tag=1;  
char inmsg, outmsg; 
MPI_Status Stat ;

MPI_Init (&argc,&argv); 
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks); 
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (rank == 0) {
  dest = source = 1;outmsg=’x’;
  rc = MPI_Send (&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  rc = MPI_Recv (&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
} 
else if (rank == 1) {
  dest = source = 0;outmsg=’y’;
  rc = MPI_Recv (&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
  rc = MPI_Send (&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

rc = MPI_Get_count (&Stat, MPI_CHAR, &count);
printf("Task %d: Received %d char(s) from task %d with tag %d \n", rank, count, Stat.MPI_SOURCE,Stat.MPI_TAG); 
MPI_Finalize ();
}
```

Comment: If you Google "MPI_Get_count", the first result answers both your questions.

Comment: [this](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Get_count.html)? `Gets the number of "top level" elements`? Isn't that the same as `size` then?

Comment: I mean `MPI_Comm_size()`

Answer (score 0):

The bit about `MPI_Get_count` is answered by the documentation in the "Output" section, further down that linked page.

As for `rc`, here's the best explanation I can offer with no access to the author of this code or any related notes. all MPI routines in the C bindings return an error code. Some compilers check whether one is dropping return values on the floor, as it might indicate an error in the code, and generate warnings where they see that happen. Thus, to keep those warnings from appearing, this code assigns the return value to the variable `rc`.

That said, many compilers also warn about setting a variable that's never used, which is the case here. An idiom for telling a compiler "yes, I know I'm ignoring this return value, leave me alone" is `(void)function_call(foo, bar, baz);` (i.e. cast the return value to `void`). This is most often seen on calls to functions whose return value really should be checked, like `write()`. Writing it on every MPI call rather than silencing an offending warning would be rather ugly.

Comment: Thanks for that but about `MPI_Get_count()`, the documentation isn't getting me there (notice the `homework` tag). What's the difference between `MPI_Get_count()` and `MPI_Comm_size()`?

Comment: Read the documentation page in full. Look at the arguments to the function, and where they came from. This function doesn't deal with a communicator at all, but with a status from a receive call.